# How to count the frequent occurrence of distinct substring (Math symbols) in a string using Java or R

Tags: java, r

I have the following String (**Sometimes there is no space between the substrings**):

```
str = "<= < / + * + cos sin (service <= service)+ * hello)rate"
```

The substring is already predefined like :

```
mathsubstring = {<=, <, / , +, cos, sin }
```

and the normal substring is predefined as well:

```
substring[]= {"service","hi","rate","world"};
```

and I want to count the frequent occurrence of each specific substring for instance:

```
The output will be :
<= = 2
<  = 1
/ = 1
+ = 3
* = 2
cos = 1
sin = 1
```

I managed to find substring from string so far see the following java code:

```
String substring[]= {"service","hi","rate","world"};

        int count=0;
        for (int j=0; j< substring.length; j++)
        {
            count=0;
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+substring[j]+"\\b");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
            while(m.find()) {
            count++;
            }
            Countsubstring = Countsubstring + count;
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a homework service. Please publish any of your code so far, demonstrating reasonable effort to solve the problem.

Comment: Does 'service' need to be counted too?

Comment: Yes but I did manage to count for normal substring the issue with math symbols

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A way with `R`, splitting the string at each `space` and then counting occurrences of different elements:

**EDIT**
With your third string and the new constraint, considering elements can be separated by space or opening or closing bracket:

```
str <- "<= < / + * + cos sin (service <= service)+ * hello)rate"
mathsubstring <- c("<=", "<", "/", "+", "cos", "sin")

t_elt <- table(strsplit(str, " |\\(|\\)"))
t_elt[mathsubstring]
```

> ```
> <=   <   /   + cos sin 
>  2   1   1   3   1   1
> ```

*If you want to know the total of occurrences of the math substrings:*

```
sum(t_elt[mathsubstring])
#[1] 9
```

---

**Previous code with former `str`**

```
table(strsplit(str, " "))

       *       /       +       <      <=     cos service     sin 
      2       1       3       1       2       1       2       1
```

You can remove `service`(or other non math symbols) afterwards if you wish to, with something like:

```
tab <- table(strsplit(str, " "))
mathsubstring <- c('<=', '<', '/', '+', 'cos', 'sin')
tab[names(tab) %in% mathsubstring]
```

---

With your second string:

```
str = "<= < / + * + cos sin service <= service + * hello rate"
table(strsplit(str, " "))

      *       /       +       <      <=     cos   hello    rate service     sin 
      2       1       3       1       2       1       1       1       2       1
```

---

Comment: You can omit `[[1]]`

Comment: @PoGibas indeed, `table` takes care of it :-)

Comment: @Cath Thanks for your answer, how I could calculate the total in the t_elt[mathsubstring] which is in this example will be 9.

Comment: @Don `sum(t_elt[mathsubstring])`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I made:

```
String str = "<= < / + * + cos sin service <= service + *";
    String[] split = str.split(" ");
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String subString : split) {
        if (!map.containsKey(subString)) {
            map.put(subString, 0);
        }
        Integer current = map.get(subString);
        map.put(subString, ++current);
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s = %s",entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()));
    }
```

Comment: For the future, you'll know that there is a `puIfAbsent()` method in Map, instead of using if!containsKey and put ;) 
And more : your 4 lines in the loop can be reduced in : `map.merge(subString, 1, Integer::sum);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a grouping and counting collectors.

```
Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                   Collectors.counting()));
```

Which results in a `Map<String, Long>` with the following content:

```
{<==2, service=2, cos=1, sin=1, *=2, +=3, <=1, /=1}
```